# Deploying Django on IIS7 or IIS7.5

Tags: python, django, iis-7, django-forms, iis-7.5

I really need help or a step-by-step guide on how to deploye a Django project on IIS7 i tried this [guide](http://www.bardiak.com/2010/12/installing-django-on-iis-7-using.html) but it didnt work, i feel like something is missing it gave me 500.0 Error

" HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred. "

any help ?

Comment: Can you give us something like contents of log file?

Comment: i am sorry but how would i access the log file its the first time for me to deploy a Django App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh this [guide](http://blog.wolfplusplus.com/?p=272) explains it all. just go with it step-by-step and here you go !!!!

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own questions on this site, but make sure you do so as if talking to another person, and mark your answer as accepted. Also, it would be useful to quote the steps you missed; remember, other people may have the same problem, and they wouldn't be pleased to find an answer that says "Ahhh it worked". Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

A complete step-by-step guide on running Django on IIS using Helicon Zoo can be found here: [zoo overview](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/run-django-apps-on-iis/) with more details provided here [zoo details](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/running-django-on-windows-with-performance-tests/)